# Adding a service reference using a WSDL which contains links that 'could not be resolved'

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I need to add a service reference using a WSDL supplied by a customer. The WSDL contains references to their WCF web service which I cannot see from my development machine. The reference is resolvable on our acceptance environment but I cannot install Visual Studio there.

I thought the point of the WSDL was that it contained all the information for VS to generate the classes necessary to talk to the WS (even without direct access to the WS).

Have have 2 questions:

- Is it possible to add this WSDL to my C# project without visibility to their WS

otherwise

- Is it possible to generate the classes from the environment that does have direct access        to the WS, without installing VS? Maybe by just installing the svcutil.exe (but I imagine this to0l will also require VS)

Comment: You should be able to run  `svcutil *.wsdl *.xsd /language:C#` to *Generate client code from local metadata documents.*  although the svcutil.exe is part of the Windows SDK I don't expect it to need much more then the exe alone...

Comment: But the svcutil tool doesn't exist on our acceptance environment because (i presume) VS isn't installed. Is there anyway to install this? Will it work with just the .net framework installed?

Comment: And running svcutil locally on the wsdl stuff doesn't work? If it doesn't just call that customer to supply the wsdl AND the xsd's.

Comment: You can copy the "bin"-folder where SVCUTIL is located to the customer-machine an call it there. Also rene is right that you can use the parameter "/language:C#" to get the file with all the functions. What I don't understand is how the XSDs are imported properly to this project. In my case it helped to install Visual Studio Community Edition on the customer-machine and to import it directly into my project.